# Redirect happening going into 302 with 2nd ajax call inside the datatables call

Tags: javascript, jquery, iis, datatables

I have the following jquery Code

Now the first ajax call is made properly and i get the headers back, when it reaches the ajax call of datatables i am getting 302.

No log is showing me enough information, I checked IIS logs and my Coldfusion Logs but both are empty, so it seems the issue is not with code.

```
$(document).on('click', '#Button',function (e) {
 
        e.preventDefault();
 
        $.ajax({
            url: "/post.cfm",
            cache: false,
            data : $('#form').serialize(),
            method: "post",
            success: function(response){
 
                $('div.results').show();
                $('.mytable').show();
                $('.mytable').html(response);
            }
        }).done(function(data) {
 
            $('#datatables').show();
            $("#datatables").DataTable({
                "bFilter": true,
                "serverSide": true,
                "deferRender":true,
                "processing": true,
                "fixedHeader": true,
                "scrollX": true,
                "columns": [
                    { "data": "CustomerName", "title": "Acccount", "autoWidth": true },
                    { "data": "flname", "title": "Completed by", "autoWidth": true,"orderable": false }
                ],
                "columnDefs": [
                    { width: 120, targets: 0 },
 
            { width: 90, targets: 1 }
                ],
                "fixedColumns": true,
                "ajax": {
                    "url" : "/post_submit.cfm",
                    "type" : "POST",
                    "data": function (d) {
                        return $.extend({}, d, {
                            "DateS": $('#DateS').val(),
                            "DateX": $('#DateX').val(),
                            "ticketType":$('#ticketType option:selected').toArray().map(function(item) { return item.value; }).join(),
                            "finalStatus": $("#finalStatus option:selected").toArray().map(function(item) { return item.value; }).join()
                        });
                    }
                },
                "language": {
                        "processing": '<i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin fa-3x fa-fw"></i><span class="sr-only">Loading...</span> ',
                        "emptyTable": "No Data available"
                },
                "scroller": {
                  loadingIndicator: true
                },
                "initComplete" : function () {
                    $('.dataTables_scrollBody thead tr').addClass('hidden');
 
                }
            });
        });
```

When the code goes to post.cfm or post_submit.cfm

Not sure what is going on, what is the best way to track down the error, i am trying everything to at least show me an error and if it can tell me an error, at least i can debug but right now, it does even go to that point

please guide

here is the error what i am getting

```
DataTables warning: table id=datatables - Invalid JSON response. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/1
```

anyone any clue what could be going wrong here, i am debugging it since last friday but no results as to i do not understand what is going wrong here

Funny part is, it is working on my localhost

Comment: `Invalid JSON response` Use fiddler or postman to check what kind of JSON it response.

Comment: but it is doing a redirect, how will it brings any data

Comment: So you mean that it should not do a redirect but query the database and return data? If so, I think you should enable failed request tracing to troubleshoot redirect and why it happened.